# How can I solve MassAssignmentSecurity error using rails version 3.2.19

Tags: ruby, ruby-on-rails-3

Can anybody please help me to resolve the following error using rails version-3.2.19 ?When i am submitting values to database this error is coming.

Error

```
ActiveModel::MassAssignmentSecurity::Error in UsersController#create

Can't mass-assign protected attributes: con_password
```

My code snippets are as follows.

views/users/new.html.erb

```
<center>
  <h1>Enter your data</h1>
  <% if @user.errors.any? %>
      <div id="error_explanation">
        <h2><%= pluralize(@user.errors.count, "error") %> prohibited this post from being saved:</h2>

        <ul>
          <% @user.errors.full_messages.each do |message| %>
              <li><%= message %></li>
          <% end %>
        </ul>
      </div>
  <% end %>
  <div class="form-div">
   <%= form_for :user,:url => {:action => 'create'} do |f|%>
    <p>
      <%= f.label :Name %>
      <%= f.text_field :name,placeholder:"Enter your name" %>
    </p>
        <p>
          <%= f.label :Email %>
          <%= f.email_field :email,placeholder:"Enter your Email" %>
        </p>
        <p>
          <%= f.label :Password %>
          <%= f.password_field :password,placeholder:"Enter your password" %>
        </p>
        <p>
          <%= f.label :password %>
          <%= f.password_field :con_password,placeholder:"Enter your password again" %>
        </p>
        <p>
          <%= f.label :content %>
          <%= f.text_field :content,placeholder:"Enter your content" %>
        </p>
        <p>
          <%= f.submit "Create User",:class => 'submit' %>
        </p>
    <% end %>
  </div>
</center>
```

controller/users_controller.rb

```
class UsersController < ApplicationController
  def index

  end
  def new
    @user=User.new
  end
  def show

  end
  def create
    @user=User.new(params[:user])
    if @user.save
      flash[:notice]="User has created successfully"
      flash[:color]="valid"
      redirect_to :action => 'index'
    else
      flash[:alert]="User could not create"
      flash[:color]="invalid"
      render :new
    end
  end
end
```

model/user.rb

```
class User < ActiveRecord::Base
  attr_accessible :content, :email, :name, :password
  EMAIL_REGEX = /\A[A-Z0-9._%+-]+@[A-Z0-9.-]+\.[A-Z]{2,4}\z/i
  validates :name, :presence => true, :uniqueness => true, :length => { :in => 3..20 }
  validates :email, :presence => true, :uniqueness => true, :format => EMAIL_REGEX
  validates :password, :confirmation => true
  validates_length_of :password, :in => 6..20, :on => :create
end
```

migrate\20150128062543_create_users.rb

```
class CreateUsers < ActiveRecord::Migration
  def change
    create_table :users do |t|
      t.string :name
      t.string :email
      t.string :password
      t.string :content

      t.timestamps
    end
  end
end
```

Please help me to solve this issue.

Answer (score 0):

Instead of `<%= f.password_field :con_password,placeholder:"Enter your password again" %>`, you should name your field `password_confirmation`, because this is what your model expects if it has `validates :password, confirmation: true`:

```
<%= f.password_field :password_confirmation, placeholder: "Enter your password again" %>
```

You also have to add `password_confirmation` to `attr_accessible` in the model.

Comment: No,again same error showing after adding your line @Marek. Do you have any other solution ?

Comment: @Subhra_agent forgot about `attr_accessible`. Check my edited answer.

Comment: After putting all data at proper place now it is working fine.